# ASPNet Group list data by property of class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have a list of data in a specific class:

```
public string id { get; set; }
public string date { get; set; }
```

What is the best way to group the list by date? For example, we have a list of 200+ entries of the class type above in any random order. Such as:

```
{ id: 324234, date: 120519 }
{ id: 354633, date: 120519 }
{ id: 9999349, date: 130519 }
```

We want to create another list which groups the items by the data such as:

```
[
   120519: [
    { id: 324234, date: 120519 }
    { id: 354633, date: 120519 }
   ],
   130519: [
    { id: 9999349, date: 130519 }
   ],
]
```

Comment: Demonstration of any potential attempt you have made so far?

Comment: Linq has a group expression. What specific problem have you encountered? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq. Sorry to be picky but fyi - properties should have capitalized names

Answer (score 0):

use `GroupBy`

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(x=> x.date);
```

`x=> x.date` is yor selector that returns a value. you can use an expression as selector:

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(x=> x.date > someDate);
```

this will result two list one for dates after someDate and one for dates before it

`GroupBy` returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<SelectorType, DataType>>`

also you can return an anonymous type as list's items. see [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)